Laravel API URL not found
I am creating an API Laravel project and it seems that there an error I can't find.
I want to get data from the table 'units'.
These are the codes:
bootstrap/app.php
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Exceptions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Middleware;

return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
->withRouting(
    web: __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php',
    commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
    health: '/up',
)
->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
    //
})
->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
    //
    })->create();

api.php
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\UnitController;

// Define the API routes for units
    Route::apiResource('units', UnitController::class);

controller
public function index()
    {
        return Unit::all();
    }

When I try to test it in Postman with the link http://localhost/api/units it says
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>

<head>
    <title>404 Not Found</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Not Found</h1>
    <p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p>
    <hr>
    <address>Apache/2.4.58 (Win64) OpenSSL/3.1.3 PHP/8.2.12 Server at localhost Port 80</address>
</body>

</html>

I checked the database .env file
APP_NAME=SKYCENTRAL
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:havtW5AahJjp4acK6Wg8PvRewVywLlwzjcp9xdA2NnQ=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_TIMEZONE=UTC
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=skycentral
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

I tried php artisan route:list
  GET|HEAD       / .......................................................................................................................................................... generated::Tn7gBH3CyKBwZe5V
  GET|HEAD       up ......................................................................................................................................................... generated::AsPiJE7sim8PezPd  


Have you registered your api.php in boostrap/app.php?Also the /api URI prefix is automatically applied to the routes so you don't need to define it explicitly in api.php file.

api.php by default already has prefix /api, you don't need to add Route::prefix('api') again. It become /api/api/units.

Did you previously cache your routes?  If yes, you need to clear them (it makes no sense to cache routes in development).  Did you manually create the api.php routes file?  The docs suggest running php artisan install:api to create it, did you do that?

It would help if you optimized after each change in routes.
php artisan optimize

OR
php artisan route:clear


didn't work :((

optimize caches config, routes, and views, which makes no sense to do in development.  It is a deployment step, not a development step: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/deployment#optimization

You need to register the api.php routes in bootstrap/app.php
return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
->withRouting(
    web: __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php',
    api: __DIR__.'/../routes/api.php', //<--- this one
    commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
    health: '/up',
)

You can simply do that with a command in laravel 11
php artisan install:api


Ok I ran the command but still the same error :(

@OsamaElEmam did you check bootstrap/app.php after that? did you run php artisan route:clear after it or php artisan route:list to check ?

yeah it was added successfully but the same error still exists

@OsamaElEmam and what is the result of php artisan route:list now after php artisan route:clear ?
